# Dexguard mapping files not being uploaded for Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0+

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

We are using Dexguard and the latest Fabric Gradle Plugin version 1.25.2. However, when we run the build with Android Plugin for Gradle 2.3.3, we see the gradle task run for '{namespace}:crashlyticsUploadDeobs{flavor + buildvariant}, but with Android PLugin for Gradle 3.0.1, we don't see this gradle task run and the logs in Crashlytics are not de-obfuscated.

My assumption is that this is the task that uploads the Dexguard mapping files up to Crashlytics.

I see the Fabric [Gradle Plugin version 1.24.0](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#august-9-2017) changelog indicates that it addressed this very issue for Proguard. Could there be another issue for Dexguard that needs to be addressed in the Fabric Gradle Plugin?

Comment: Can you sanitize and share these logs: 

On Linux / Windows:~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log 

On Mac:~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Comment: thanks. I found out what the issue was and answered it below, along with a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from GuardSquare I was able to identify the issue. Dexguard 8.1 provides a 'dexguard-partial' plugin that let's you exclude dexguard for certain buildTypes. By excluding dexguard on debug builds, you get faster build times. However, this 'dexguard-partial' plugin does not appear to be recognized by Fabric's plugin for Gradle. Therefore, those tasks for uploading the Dexguard mapping files to Crashlytics, never run.

I was able to resolve this issue by switching from the 'dexguard-partial', back over to the 'dexguard' plugin and adding the following conditional check to ensure the plugin is only included for Release builds:

```
getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Release")
```

This keeps our build times down for debug builds, by excluding dexguard for those builds. And resolves the Crashlytics issue by including dexguard for release builds.

Comment: where should this line go? @Jason Grife

Comment: It would be a conditional check wrapping the dexguard plugin line.

Comment: thanks for the help ,
i tried adding this line to app.gradle
seems that i have to comment other dexguard setup also